# Power supply slow rise time and ringing

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, toggle-switch, ringing

I have this [Power Supply EA-PSI 9200-15T](https://docs.rs-online.com/2983/0900766b815d73d4.pdf).

My input voltage to a board is 28.8V. No load current is drawn from the power supply.

1. [image]

With reference to the above diagram, if I connect the board to the power supply and turn the power supply ON directly, I get this waveform:

[image]

The rise time of the power supply from 0V to 28.8V is around 10ms here.

2. [image]

But now, if I connect a toggle switch between the power supply and the board, and I keep the switch in OFF position first. Now, I turn ON the power supply and then I turn ON the toggle switch as shown above, I get this waveform:

[image]

Ignoring the ringing, the rise time of the power supply from 0V to 28.8V is 20us.

My questions:

1. Why does the rise time vary when I connect and turn ON the power supply directly and when I connect and turn ON using a toggle switch?
2. Why is there ringing in the supply when I connect it through a toggle switch?

Can someone please help with these questions.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are doing from the question as it currently stands. My advice is draw a circuit and show on that circuit where you are connecting the probes. Be unambiguous when you talk about "board" and "load". I understand "load" but "board" could mean anything as in *If I connect the board to the power supply*. Also what does *turn the board ON directly* mean. It's guesswork and I don't want to guess.

Comment: OK just a minute will update

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Please show your probe setup with a photo.

Comment: You say "If I connect the board to the power supply and turn the board ON directly" ... Did you mean "If I connect the board to the power supply and turn the **power supply** ON directly"

Comment: @bobflux , yes . I meant that only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But now, If I connect a toggle switch between the power supply and the board. And I keep the switch in OFF position first. Now, I turn ON the power supply and then I turn ON the toggle switch as shown above, I get this waveform.

This is a timeless classic ;)

The power supply has capacitors on the output, which are charged to output voltage.

The board has capacitors on the input.

The wires have inductance. Maybe there is a ferrite bead on the board input also, adding inductance.

Thus you get a LC resonant circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSsD92.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch closes, it will ring. If peak voltage is high enough, some component can fry. Q of this resonance is:

\$ Q = \frac{1}{R} \sqrt \frac{L}{C} \$

If you intend to use a switch on the DC power input, you have to bring the Q down to avoid the overvoltage peak.

- You can't decrease L since that's fixed by the length of wires.
- You can increase C by adding caps on the input of your board. Note C represents the series combination of the caps in the supply and the caps on the board.
- You can increase R by adding a largish value electrolytic with some ESR, or a smaller MLCC in series with a resistor, straight on the input.

Tune the cap ESR (or the resistor) to get good dampening of LC resonance.

If you have a ferrite on the input, you'll have to do the math or simulate it with proper model to get good damping.

---

Answering this comment:

> the ringing should be observable even when I don't connect the supply through the toggle switch right? Why is my first waveform different from the second waveform

If you turn on the power supply itself, it doesn't ring. Why? The resonant circuit still exists but it is not excited.

When the power supply is turned on, it slowly ramps up its output voltage. Besides avoiding any inrush current in your board's capacitors, this slow waveform does not contain the sharp edge and high-frequency components that would excite the RLC circuit. A resonant circuit cannot create a frequency that wasn't there in the original signal, it is only a passive filter. Consider the frequency response of this random lowpass filter from the 'net at various Q. For high Q there is a huge peak. But if the frequency of this peak is not present in the signal, there will be no visible resonance. Voltage steps excite it because in the frequency domain the sharp edge of a voltage step contains a wide band of frequencies...

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. So, there is no way to eliminate this ringing, right? It can only be reduced but cannot be eliminated. Am I correct?

Comment: If the RLC circuit has good damping factor, it won't ring at all. Here is an [example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Step-response-of-an-RLC-circuit-for-different-values-of-the-damping-factor-z_fig13_263713877) of step response versus damping factor.

Comment: Ok. But the ringing should be observable even when I don't connect the supply through the toggle switch right? Why is my first waveform different from the second waveform

Comment: The toggle switch waveform does not introduce any switch denounce right?

Comment: Answer edited. And... yeah, you could also get switch bounce on top, but once the caps after the switch are charged that won't be visible unless the board draws enough current so the voltage ramps down between bounces.

Comment: @Newbie: that frequency response chart for different values of Q contains a blue line in the middle, which corresponds to the math suggested by analogsystemsrf in his response. Not sure if the formula implies a resistor in series with the choke or in parallel with the choke.

Comment: If you add a resistor it should be in series with the cap that causes the resonance. That way it doesn't dissipate any power. Putting the resistor in series with the inductor would mean all supply current flows through the resistor which would cause losses.

Comment: Putting the resistor in parallel with the choke would also suppress the resonant Q, and would only consume AC energy. It would also let some extra EMI through, unfortunately. For DC, the choke would be the path of least resistance. Putting a resistor in series in the LC circuit certainly does suppress the Q and the EMI, but indeed at the cost of power dissipation... I've seen this suggested for scenarios where a bit of power dissipation is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use the simple expression

- Rdampen = sqrt(L / C)

as predictor of what value of R will provide approximately smooth response.

I used Q = X_L/R = X_C/R as the underlying maths (the initial axioms in a proof) along with goal of Q = 1.

I used "Q = 1" as basis for the proof, instead of any requirement for a specific dampening coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to second what @bobflux says. It is indeed a classic - but to me, it's also a classic in low-volt DC power supply distribution, which seems harmless from a distance, but can bite you in subtle ways if you don't pay attention.

Apart from that cute resonant side-effect, your main problem is IMO the capacitive *inrush* pulse. You are switching two hefty capacitors together, each at a different voltage level - and you're facing a short circuit current, limited only by the choke that completes the LC resonator. The right way to go about this would be using an [inrush limiting device](http://support.fccps.cz/download/adv/frr/inrush/inrush.html) of some sort - but their actual "density of occurrence" in my reality is pretty rare. Feedback-limited constant current for a limited amount of time, that's my preferred solution. Hardly anyone uses that. On occasions I witness an NTC in some PSU's.

EDIT - a few words on switching before vs. after the mains SMPS PSU:

Not sure how much you know about the internals of Switch Mode Power Supplies. Generally there's a capacitor on the input, an RF power driver, a transformer, a rectifier working into some output filtering capacitors (low ESR elyt or polymer). The RF stage including the transformer has a limited capability to transfer electric power. While the caps alone can deliver peak currents (short circuit) of well over a hundred amps, the transformer stage can only deliver its nominal value, whatever that is - 5A DC filtered output maybe?

t = C * V / I

For instance, if the ouput cap has 2200 uF, the nominal voltage is 24V and the max current is 5A, the slope would last about 10 ms.

Plus, there may be an artificial limit (in the PSU feedback) on the steepness of the initial ramp of the output caps charging on power-up. For instance, PC power supplies could make faster ramps at full steam (under a millisecond on its low-volt outputs) but the ATX spec says that the ramp should last between 1 and 25 ms, so the dV/dt has to be limited artificially.

So if you switch the mains input to your mains PSU, the inrush (if there is any, and it will possibly be limited by an NTC) happens on the primary side of the PSU. The steep ramp and the associated inrush current does not propagate through the RF stage and transformer, to the circuit between your PSU output and the load (albeit capacitive too). The load gets charged in milliseconds, along with your PSU output, as opposed to the microseconds in case you switch the secondary 28V rail, capacitor to capacitor.

By putting the switch at the mains primary side, you have just moved the inrush event one stage further away from your DC-powered device. On the one hand, you have kinda swept the problem under the carpet. On the other hand, this may as well mean problem solved, at least for the moment.

Comment: Ok. But the ringing should be observable even when I don't connect the supply through the toggle switch right? Why is my first waveform different from the second waveform

Comment: Thanks for asking that question. You have a fine oscilloscope, so you'd better be aware of its excellent features. Notice that your first screenshot is taken with a timebase zoom of 32 ms/div. And the second screenshot, with the nice wobble, is at 10 us/div. Notice what slope (dV/dt) has the pulse in your second picture, compared to the slope in the first picture. Have you tried zooming in the first picture to 10 us/div? If not, try that. Notice what it does to the upper end of the slope. Can you see that ringing? If not, are you still surprised? :-) Feel free to ask again if I speak puzzles.

Comment: And I'll add a less mystical response to the body of my answer.

Comment: Actually Bobflux has nailed it for you, with his paragraph on resonant circuits. It's the steep voltage step and the associated inrush current spike that give energy to the ringing glitch.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have tried to search for the internal circuitry of Bench Power Supplies to understand this. If possible, please provide some links to further understanding of bench power supply stage. I never thought there would be an RF Stage inside a power supply? What does a RF stage do for a power supply? Any explanation or document link could help me greatly.

Comment: All the mains-powered SMPS are principally the same, whether it's a PC PSU, a bench supply, a phone charger or whatever. Having the transformer run at a high frequency allows the PSU to be smaller, lower weight, have a narrower load regulation and ultimately cheaper to make. Watch this animation (the audio track is not very useful): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8ld7ta3sa0   Here is a simple design with the TL494 PWM controller: https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2015/6/1/8/51/49/569/ons_/manual/ncv494.jpg

Comment: Thank you. I just have 2 queries. What is the purpose of the RF Stage (Radio Frequency Stage) in a power supply? And When I connect my board to the power supply and turn ON the board directly, the rise time of the power supply is slow (around 10ms) which is due to the charging of the Output Capacitors of the power supply , right? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The "RF stage" is my own vocabulary, others might have better names. Its purpose is to squeeze maximum power out of a mechanically small transformer :-) Yes the PSU output capacitors are charging slowly either way, since the moment you apply mains voltage to the PSU input. And if you put a switch between the PSU and your (capacitive) load, by the time you flip that switch, your lab PSU has already been charged for a while, so its inherently slow ramp has been over by that time. I suggest that you start a new topic about SMPS principles if you have further questions.